# Login and pay with Amazon integration issue

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, payment, login-with-amazon

So, I'm trying to integrate the Login and Pay with Amazon widget, and I'm encountering some problems.

So, I have my seller account all set up on

> https://sellercentral.amazon.de/gp/

I have access to my API credentials, and I need to get a LWA client.
So, I have registered on

> https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/homepage.htm

in order to create an application. I have set up the application, on web settings I have completed the required URL's, and got my client ID.

In the js for the Login and Pay with Amazon widget, I have replaced all the info needed: Client Id, merchant Id etc.
But when I try to make a test login, I receive the following error :

> 400 Bad Request Unknown client_id

The Pay With Amazon documentation is not very clear, and I can't seem to find anywhere a list with the error codes.

If anybody has an idea, let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you actually set everything right up? You're not using a dummy id that you simply have to change to your specifically provided client id?

Comment: @Jonast92 nope. The client Id is the one that I've copied from "Web settings" section.

Answer (score 0):

you should create your Login with Amazon application using https://sellercentral.amazon.de instead of the .com site. They are separate accounts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing this piece of code:

```
window.onAmazonLoginReady = function() { amazon.Login.setClientId('CLIENT_ID'); }
```